# Local homomorphisms on a fibered surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, surfaces, algebraic-curves, localization

Let $f:X\to C$ be a surjective homomorphism of a regular projective surface onto a regular projective curve over  a field $k$. Assume that $f(x)=c$ and that $Y\subset X$ is an integral curve such that $Y\subset f^{-1}(c)$. Then we have the following local injective homomorphisms:

- $f^{\#}_x:\mathcal O_{C,c}\to \mathcal O_{X,x}$.
- If $y$ is the generic point of $Y$, then $f^{\#}_y:\mathcal O_{C,c}\to \mathcal O_{X,y}$
- If $\mathfrak p$ is the local equation of $y$ at $x$ then $\mathcal O_{X,y}=(\mathcal O_{X,x})_{\mathfrak p}$. In particular there is an embedding $i:\mathcal O_{X,x}\hookrightarrow O_{X,y} $. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700825/local-equation-of-a-divisor-localization-and-local-ring-at-a-point).

I believe that the following equality holds (just an intuition):
$$f^{\#}_y=i\circ f^{\#}_x$$

But how can I prove it?

Comment: All the maps in question come from the map induced on function fields of $X$ and $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that $x \in Y$, then this is a triviality. We have a map

$f^{\sharp}\colon \mathcal{O}_{C} \rightarrow f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_{X}$ of sheaves on $C$. Further, we have

$\mathcal{O}_{C,c} = \lim_{\{U \subset C \mid c \in U \subset C\}} \mathcal{O}_C(U)$

$\lim_{\{U \subset C \mid x \in f^{-1}(U) \subset X\}} f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_X(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,x} = \lim_{\{V \subset X \mid x \in V \subset X \}}\mathcal{O}_X(V)$

$\lim_{\{U \subset C \mid y \in f^{-1}(U) \subset X\}} f_{\ast}\mathcal{O}_X(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,y}= \lim_{\{V \subset X \mid y \in V \subset X\}}\mathcal{O}_X(V)$

Now the canonical maps arrise, because $c \in U \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}(U) \Rightarrow y \in f^{-1}(U)$, and the natural maps arising from the limits above are exactly the maps you asked for.

On the other hand, if $x \notin Y$, I do not believe that what you asked is true, as the morphism $\mathcal{O}_{X,x} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X,y}$ generally does not exist.